# iPhone 4s, version 5.1.1 upgrade to 8.1.2

Tags: upgrade

I downloaded the Iphone4,1_8.1.2_12b440_restore.ipsw on my laptop and I pressed shift plus update it started extracting and said unknown error3194 finally after finishing. I am frustrated and I really need your guys help. I wanted to know how to fix this problem and finally upgrade my phone. 
I have 5gb Free space on my phone
I have iTunes version 12.0.1.26

Comment: First, your iTunes is out of date. Second, are you certain it was the correct file? Best is to let iTunes fetch it, then even if it fails, you can check you have the correct file name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your iTunes is out of date [current is 12.1.0.50].

Second, are you certain it was the correct file? Best is to let iTunes fetch it, then even if it fails, you can check you have the correct file name.

Third - are you certain Apple are still signing 8.1.2? They usually only give it a few days after a new release before stopping the old versions. You'd be better off trying 8.2

Comment: What is the correct file name of iTunes update 8.2?And website which I can downloAd it from because direct download of the file from iTunes always fails me

Comment: DL links are always easy to Google - try  http://osxdaily.com/2015/03/09/ios-8-2-released-ipsw-download/